# How to extract url data from Reddit API using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, reddit

I'm trying to extract the image post URLs from a subreddit feed, and render `<img>` elements on my page.

Been trying to hack together the `.getJSON()` [Flickr example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#example-0) from the jQuery Docs for a while now and I'm not getting anywhere.

Code in question:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json', function (data) {
  $.each(data.children, function (i, item) {
    $('<img/>').attr("src", url).appendTo("#images");
  });
});
```

In the body, I have the element: `div#images`

I understand that I need to use JSONP, but not sure how. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using the wrong url. Use this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) { 
    // Do whatever you want with it.. 
});
```

**EDIT :** Working example based on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/) in the comments.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) { 
    $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
    });
});
```

You should use `data.data.children` and not `data.children`

Comment: @ZachL I tried running your fiddle and it isn't working either. I'm not having issues extracting what I want from the data variable. My function never even gets called.

Comment: @ZachL It appears to be working in Firefox but not Chrome on OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: @Talon876 [Glad you sorted it out](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1ioezx/reddit_api_and_jsonp_not_working/) (the problem was adblock.)

Answer (score 0):

For internet friends being lost here:

```js
fetch("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json")
  .then(r => r.json()).then((r) => {
     r.data.children.forEach((i) => {
       try{
         document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("img"),{src: i.data.thumbnail}))
       } catch (error){console.log(error.message)}
 })})
```